# Does Substitution of Logical Equivalents hold for minimal logic?

Tags: proof-theory, natural-deduction

Suppose that minimal logic proves that $\psi_1\leftrightarrow\psi_2$, does it follow that minimal logic proves $\varphi[\theta/\psi_1]\leftrightarrow\varphi[\theta/\psi_2]$?